# xcode NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException , when try unarchive file

Tags: ios, xcode

This is an error throw by xcode:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: '***
>   -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeInt64ForKey:]: value for key (rating) is not an integer number'

This is a part of the class to create Meal object:

> //MARK: Properties
>
> ```
> var rating: Int
> var name: String
> var photo: UIImage?
> ```
>
> //MARK: Path
>
> ```
> static let DocumentDirectory = NSFileManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains:.UserDomainMask).first!
>
> static let ArchivelUrl = DocumentDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("meals")
> ```
>
> //MARK: NSCoding
>
> ```
> func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
>     aCoder.encodeObject(name, forKey: propertyKey.nameKey)
>     aCoder.encodeObject(photo, forKey: propertyKey.photoKey)
>     aCoder.encodeInteger(rating, forKey: propertyKey.ratingKey)
>
> }
> required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
>     let name = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(propertyKey.nameKey) as! String
>     let photo = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(propertyKey.photoKey) as? UIImage
>     let rating = aDecoder.decodeIntegerForKey(propertyKey.ratingKey)
>     //must call to designate initiallizer 
>     self.init(name: name,photo: photo,rating: rating)
> }
> ```

and this is the archiver and unarchiver :

> //MARK: NSCoding
>
> ```
> func saveMeal(){
>     let isSuccessfulSave = NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(meals, toFile:Meal.ArchivelUrl.path!)
>
>     if !isSuccessfulSave {
>         print("Failed to save")
>     }
>     else{
>         print("saved")
>     }
> }
>
>  func loadMeal() -> [Meal]? {
>   return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(Meal.ArchivelUrl.path!) as [Meal] }
> ```

I followed this tutorial in apple site:[https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson10.html

The example project worked. I tried to copy my code to their project files and it worked too. So I think there is a difference setup here!

Comment: The code looks OK.  Time for the debugger as that's what it's there for.  Check values being passed in are correct (especially `Meal.ArchiveUrl.path`).

Comment: @Droppy I think it not a problem `file:///Users/MY_acc/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B64C66A2-E8F4-4E4F-81B4-513650917A5D/data/Containers/Data/Application/4910292B-5BA1-4EBE-B88D-6E9AE1A90B6B/Documents/meals'

Comment: Having same issue. Works fine on initial build, but after saving any new Meal item, doesn't not load.

Comment: Are you sure you are using encodeInteger (not encodeObject) while encoding the "rating"?

Comment: @dellos I am facing same issue did you got the solution?

Answer (score 20):

The problem I solved by replacing the following code:

```
let rating = aDecoder.decodeIntegerForKey(propertyKey.ratingKey)
to
let rating = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(propertyKey.ratingKey) as! Int
```

I guess you have compiled and save rating as object instead of Integer before, so when you decode the object as Integer, it will tell you the object is not Integer (cause compiler doesn't know what the object type is)

Or You could print your `Meal.ArchivelUrl.path!` and delete the existing `meal.text`, and delete the app in your simulator, then Compile your code which you posted here again. I think that will be fine (at least fine for me).

Comment: Thanks it helped me !

Comment: Worked for me yeah

Answer (score 5):

Alright So I finally figured the problem. It was with `optional` values getting encoded while storing the value. And since swift encoder function don't raise any warning even when non integer values are being passed on function which is made to accept only integer.

*Solution is to encode `Int` value with `!`.*

Check out my class for more detail. Note that `Permission` and `Office` are classes.

```
class User : NSObject, NSCoding {
    var bio : String! = ""
    var careerLevel : Int! = 0

    var office : Office!
    var permissions : Array<Permission>!

    init (userDetail:Dictionary<String, Any>) {
        super.init()

        //set values
        self.setValues(detail: userDetail)
    }

    func setValues(detail:Dictionary<String, Any>)  {
        if let value = detail["hash_token"] as? String {self.accessToken = value}

        //now get user detail
        if var information = detail["user_details"] as? Dictionary<String, Any> {
            if let value = information["bio"] {self.bio = String(describing: value)}
            if let value = information["career_level"]  {self.careerLevel = Int(String.init(describing: value))!}

            //set office information
            if let officeDictionary = information["office_detail"] as? Dictionary<String, Any> {
                let office_ = Office.init(detail: officeDictionary, id: officeId)
                self.office = office_
            }

            //now set permission information
            if self.permissions != nil {self.permissions.removeAll(); self.permissions = nil}
            self.permissions = Array<Permission>()
            if  let permissionArray = information["permissions"] as? Array<Any>{
                for permissionDictionary in permissionArray {
                    let permission : Permission = Permission.init(detail: permissionDictionary as! Dictionary<String, Any>)
                    self.permissions.append(permission)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    required init(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        //Error here "missing argument for parameter name in call
        self.bio = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "bio") as! String
        self.careerLevel = decoder.decodeInteger(forKey: "careerLevel")

        //
        self.office = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "office") as! Office
        self.permissions = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "permissions") as! Array<Permission>

        super.init()
    }

    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        //
        aCoder.encode(self.bio!, forKey: "bio")
        aCoder.encode(self.careerLevel!, forKey:"careerLevel")

        //
        aCoder.encode(self.office!, forKey: "office")
        aCoder.encode(self.permissions!, forKey: "permissions")
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a really poor solution. You could have used something like encode(self.bio ?? 0) or if let bio = self.bio { encode() }. As written you have a bunch of ticking time bombs in. this code.

Comment: That's one of the problems with Swift. It's loaded with ticking time bombs by design it seems.

Answer (score 1):

[This GitHub issue](https://github.com/uchicago-mobi/2016-Winter-Forum/issues/45) suggests a fix may be to do `Hardware > Erase all Content and Settings` from the Simulator application